# What is this array-like notation of registers in datasheets?

Tags: sensor, datasheet, register

I am reading [BMP280 datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST-BMP280-DS001-11.pdf) (pressure&temperature sensor). On different pages they use the following notation:
$$register\text{_}name[a:b]$$ where a, b are integers. For example, on page 13 "Enabling/disabling the temperature measurement and oversampling setting are  selected  through  the  **osrs_t[2:0]**  bits  in  control register 0xF4".

How to interpret this notation?

Comment: In x86 microcode descriptions we would say its bits 2, 1 and 0. Might be the same in their notation.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, from left to right? So [a:b] means b, b+1, ..., a bits?

Comment: Bit 2:0 means bits 0 to 2. There's no "left and right", there's the LSB which is bit 0 and then count from there.

Comment: These are the notations borrowed from the chip design language, Verilog or VHDL. Marketing and technical writers just use them for simplicity and convenience.

Comment: @AliChen - did you know that VHDL was originally conceived as a way of describing the behaviour of existing chips, not as a way of designing them?  This is precisely the kind of application VHDL was originally supposed to be used for.

Comment: @Jules, no, I didn't know that chips can exist without definitions of what they do. Being on IC design teams for 20+ years, I hear this first time :-(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those denote the bits within the register.

The bits are number 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 so register 0xF4 is build up:

```
Control register 0xF4 bits: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
                                      <--->
                                   osrs_t bits
```

In <----> you can set the temperature measurement and oversampling setting (osrs_t).

In Table 5 of page 13 you can see exactly the values and their meaning for these 3 bits:

[image: Datasheet excerpt]

If osrs_t would be stored in the MSB first 3 bits it would be mentioned as osrs_t[7:5], and if the entire byte is used, normally the [] will not be shown.

Answer (score 1):

It very likely means bits. `osrs_t[2:0]` would mean selected through bits 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: It is not "likely", it is with 110% confidence.

Comment: @AliChen: Unless it's an IBM document. Then it means bits 31, 30, and 29 or bits 63, 62, and 61. ;-)

Comment: @R.., that's probably why their hardware is out of business :-(

Comment: @R.. I did actually have the dysfunctional PowerPC hardware manuals in mind when I wrote "very likely".